# docker-compose unable to build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, django-celery, celerybeat

This is the Docker file I am building using docker-compose build, and its always stuck on 9/38 and its building process is not finishing. Here is the main code of the docker file:

```
`###########
## BUILDER ##
###########

# pull official base image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && \ 
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-psycopg2 apache2 apache2-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev

#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt update -y && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client wget python3-psycopg2 apache2 build-essential libpq-dev wkhtmltopdf && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 8080
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./start.sh"]
CMD ["sh", "-c", "./start.sh"]
```

I am building this dockerfile, but its getting stuck, the error seems to be :

```
[celery-worker stage-1  2/14] RUN apt update -y && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client wget python3-psycopg2 apache2 build-essential libpq-dev wkht  248.8s 
 => [celery-worker builder 3/8] RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-psycopg2 apache2 apache2-dev default-li  248.8s
```

Error message:

```
CANCELED [celery-worker builder 3/8] RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-psycopg2 apache2 apache2-dev d  433.7s 
 => ERROR [celery-beat stage-1  2/14] RUN apt update -y && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client wget python3-psycopg2 apache2 build-essential libpq-dev   433.7s 
------
 > [celery-beat stage-1  2/14] RUN apt update -y && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client wget python3-psycopg2 apache2 build-essential libpq-dev wkhtmltopdf && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:
0.771
0.771 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
0.771
3.958 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [147 kB]
8.457 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
13.23 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
22.09 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
173.5 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
191.7 Ign:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages
198.9 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
228.9 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
239.2 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [47.3 kB]
262.9 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
429.6 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
433.6 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
433.6 Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
433.6   Connection timed out [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]
433.6 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
433.6 Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
433.6   Connection timed out [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]
433.6 Ign:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
433.6 Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
433.6   Connection timed out [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]
433.7 Fetched 294 kB in 7min 13s (680 B/s)
433.7 Reading package lists...
433.7 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection timed out [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]
433.7 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt update -y && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client wget python3-psycopg2 apache2 build-essential libpq-dev wkhtmltopdf && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*"
```

Comment: I don't see any error messages there.

Comment: @larsks but its not builing and when i cancel these task, the later ones are also not building

Comment: Hello @DeepanshuJoshi . update your question with the error message

Comment: it is timing out for deb.debian.org. `Connection timed out [IP: 199.232.22.132 80]`, might be firewall blocking the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the yml configuration file you provided, it seems to be incomplete.Missing the `COPY` or `ADD` command to copy the application code into the Docker image. Without this command, the application code won't be included in the image, and the subsequent commands may fail.

The commands `RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./start.sh"] CMD ["sh", "-c", "./start.sh"]` will not run without copying the shell file into the image.

The timeout is probably a network issue, check your internet connection

Here is the updated Dockerfile that icludes the `COPY  . /app` directive:

```
###########
## BUILDER ##
###########

# pull official base image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY  . /app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && \ 
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc python3-psycopg2 apache2 apache2-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev

#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-slim

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apt update -y && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client wget python3-psycopg2 apache2 build-essential libpq-dev wkhtmltopdf && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 8080
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./start.sh"]
CMD ["sh", "-c", "./start.sh"]
```